# Unable to do a cUrl request

Tags: php, xml, web-services, curl, soap

I have a `cUrl` request to a third party API. But it throws me an error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body><soap:Fault><soap:Code><soap:Value>soap:Receiver</soap:Value></soap:Code><soap:Reason><soap:Text xml:lang="en">
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---&gt; System.Xml.XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseRootLevelWhitespace()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.SoapEnvelopeReader.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlReader.MoveToContent()
   at       System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.SoapEnvelopeReader.MoveToContent()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocolHelper.GetRequestElement()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.Soap12ServerProtocolHelper.RouteRequest()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.Initialize()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean&amp; abortProcessing)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---</soap:Text></soap:Reason><soap:Detail /></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

**This is my code**

```
    //First fetch the GUID*/
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://thirdpary.asmx?op=action");

    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);

    $postarray = array(
    'hashKey'=>'some-secret-key',           
    'username'=>'username',     
    'password'=>'password'      
    );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postarray));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    $response3 = curl_exec($ch);
    //print_r($response3 );exit;
    if(curl_errno($ch)){
        echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    $y=0;

    $response3 = simplexml_load_string($response3) or die("Error: Cannot create object");

    print_r($response3 );
    exit;
```

The script is supposed to return me the `guid` of the user credentials, I am sending.

I am already getting successful responses from the same API for some other requests using cUrl.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Does the API allow you to post the field variables to it, or does it require an XML body to process?  The error states that the data you are passing it are invalid, which means it doesn't like whatever you are currently sending it.

Comment: The API is allowing four methods: SOAP 1.1,SOAP 1.2,HTTP GET and HTTP POST

Comment: HTTP POST with hashKey=string&username=string&password=string

Comment: Whatever you expect of what you do, the other side is not understanding it that way. From the error message alone it's expected to be a SOAP request and for sure it fails as good as a fail could be as you don't do a SOAP request (as the exception name shows) one and you don't even provide XML (as the exception message communicates). So what is your concrete question? What you do is obviously the wrong approach, but what is your question? And add those other requests to your question so you can show how a working request is build.

Comment: @hakre: Thanks! I just wanted to make sure that the server is handling my http post request as a soap request and that is why it is causing the problem! I will reimplement the same in soap.